# What does the dot symbol mean?

Tags: logic, notation

```
A = B ⇔ (∀x.x ∈ A ⇔ x ∈ B)
```

What does "∀x.x" mean?
This expression means: saying 2 sets are equal, is equivalent to saying they're the same set, right?
Thank you.

Comment: Looks to me like it means ,

Comment: or a ":" instead (mistyping)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a separator between $\forall x$ and the formula $x\in A\iff x\in B$. It means that the context of $x$ is fixed to be that of the quantified value throughout the rest of the formula.

Comment: Oh, like parentheses (but until the end of the expression)? It makes sense...
Not exactly like parentheses but I think I got it. Thank you.

Comment: @SadSeven - **exactly** like parentheses; you may (and I think it is better) rewrite it as : $A = B \leftrightarrow (\forall x)(x \in A \leftrightarrow x \in B)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Alright, thank you very much! :)